# How to easily transfer child nodes in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit

In a game, at a certain time, I need to group certain nodes, so I make them child of another node, but then I don't want them to be children of the node anymore, and I would like to transfer them back as simple children of the scene.
**How would you do that ?**

Comment: remove from first node then add to scene.

Answer (score 1):

This *should* do it (untested):

```
for (SKNode *node in groupNode.children) {
    [node removeFromParent];
    CGPoint pos = node.position;
    pos.x += groupNode.position.x;
    pos.y += groupNode.position.y;
    node.position = pos;
    [[groupNode parent] addChild:node];
}
[groupNode removeFromParent];
```